# PHP MySQL Column Loop if name is similar?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

i am not sure this exists in PHP/MySQL,

i want to return multiple columns in a mysql database that have a similar names dynamically and they are null/"" then don't return the row, due to the fact you can't add duplicate Column names i am not sure how to do this?

i was doing this but looking for a more dynamic way as i don't want rely use the array, by passing a string of lets say "name" only is that possible? sort of like the MySQL select "SELECT * FROM db WHERE name = 'Jack';"

```
$names = array("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4");

foreach ($names as $value) {

            if($row [$value] > 0){
                //
            }else{
                if($row [$value] == null){
                    //
                }else{
                    echo $row[$value];
                }
            }
        }
```

here is the structure of the database - lets say the "" below are blank;

```
id category subcat name1 name2 name3 name4 name5
1  people   names  jack  bob   sue   anna  ""
2  people   names  name  name  ""    ""    ""
3  animals  ...    ..    .     .. etc
```

heres my php mysql query;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE category = 'people'"; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $names = array("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4","name5");

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo $row["subcat"]."<br>";

            foreach ($names as $value) {
                if($row [$value] > 0){
                    //
                }else{
                    if($row [$value] == null){
                        //
                    }else{
                        echo $row[$value]."<br>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: row, column, value? are you sure that you understand difference between them in mysql?

Comment: Please show your database schema, sample data, and and what you're trying to return. Your description is very unclear.

Comment: Having columns like `name1`, `name2`, etc. is usually a bad table design. You should have a relation table with a row for each name, then you can use a `JOIN`.

Comment: @Lashane & Barmar thanks.. i have updated my question with the database schema & query, i didn't want to have multiple tables. wanted to have them all inside one table or is it impossible to do this?

Comment: @Barmar how could i do a JOIN statement if lets say the column names, name1/name2/name3...were getting updated more over time dynamically.. name6/name7/name8 etc...

Comment: That's the point of using a table rather than columns. In the relation table, everything will just be in a single `name` column. Each name will be in a different row of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be with a separate `names` table:

```
item_id name
1       jack
1       bob
1       sue
1       anna
2       name1
2       name2
```

Then you can join this with the original table:

```
SELECT d.id, d.category, d.subcat, n.name
FROM db AS d
JOIN names AS n ON n.item_id = d.id
WHERE d.category = 'people'
ORDER BY d.id
```

Using your existing structure, you can do this in the PHP:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['subcat'] . "<br>";
    foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
        if (substr($col, 0, 4) == 'name' && $value != '') {
            echo $value . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, unfortunately i can't use another table (as i have stated) needs to be all in that structure i have posted regardless if its incorrect.

Comment: oh ok just saw the last part of your message sorry.. just tried it its not working? - will try debug it but that exactly what i was looking for... thanks @Barmar that is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You want to get multiple rows from different columns and rows have similar values. But one value can't show up twice? and can't be null?

This you can do with use of [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) statement and to check if value is not null you can use after WHERE statement > IS NOT NULL. So whole sql statement would look like example below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name FROM table WHERE YourColumn IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is not what i want to do. i want to dynamically loop selected columns that have the same keyword as the KEY not the VALUE, please take a look at my updated question @nejc-rodošek

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE category = 'people'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$names = array("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4","name5");

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo $row["subcat"]."<br>";

        foreach ($names as $value) {
            if(in_array($value, $names)){
                // the value is in the names array
                echo $row[$value]."<br>";
                ...
            }else{
                // the value is not in the names array
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the code in my question works. i do not want to use an array! i want a more dynamic way of doing this.

Comment: @whitedeath unfortunately for you, the `$names` is an array.

Comment: yes but i did not want to use it, take a look at the answer i accepted thats exactly how i needed it to function. thanks for replying though